# readelf-like tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, function, symbols

Is there a tool for reading Mac OS X binaries that would print information about relocation tables and symbol offsets similar to this `readelf` output?

```
readelf -r app

Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x5ec contains 2 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
08049d58  00001706 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __gmon_start__
08049d60  00000305 R_386_COPY        08049d60   _ZSt4cout

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x5fc contains 13 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
08049d24  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804868c   print
08049d28  00000207 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804869c   _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1E
08049d2c  00000507 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080486ac   _ZStlsISt11char_traits
08049d30  00000607 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080486bc   _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
08049d34  00000707 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   08048664   _init
08049d38  00000807 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080486dc   sleep
08049d3c  00000907 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080486ec   _ZNKSsixEj
08049d40  00000b07 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080486fc   _ZNKSs4sizeEv
08049d44  00000c07 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804870c   __libc_start_main
08049d48  00000d07 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   08048ae4   _fini
08049d4c  00001307 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804872c   _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_tr
08049d50  00001507 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804873c   __gxx_personality_v0
08049d54  00001607 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   0804874c   _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1E
```

In this example, `print` is a function loaded from a shared library (I wrote) at runtime.  `readelf` is able to display information about its location inside the `app` binary.

Comment: Would `nm` do the trick?

Comment: It doesn't print enough information.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Using [Macports](https://www.macports.org/):

1. [Install macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php).
2. Using macports `port install binutils`
3. `gobjdump -p /path/to/app`

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

1. [Install Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
2. Do `brew update && brew install binutils`
3. `/usr/local/path/to/gobjdump -p /path/to/app` # or follow instructions to add it to your PATH

There are, of course, many other command-line options.  Note that the binutils port cautions that installing it may cause other ports to fail to build.  Having it around to port install/look at something/port uninstall can still be handy.

It's rather amazing that there isn't already some native tool to do this.

Comment: If you use Homebrew, then you can install this via "brew install binutils".

Comment: For Homebrew users, as @louielouie mentioned, `brew install binutils` then all tools will be prefixed with a `g`, ie `greadelf`. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/binutils.rb

Comment: I get a message: `gobjdump: Matching formats: elf32-littlearm elf32-littlearm-symbian elf32-littlearm-vxworks`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you can use greadelf -Ws /path/to/your/so/files

Answer (score 26):

otool -l test.o

Comment: Nope, it also doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You can do this with otool, you just need to pass additional options.   man otool for details.

Comment: `otool -Sv libtest.a` is nicer, or `otool -STMRIHGv <path/to/library>` for any kind of library (`*.a`, `*.so`, `*.dylib`). `otool` is available at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool` after Xcode is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this with `.so` files.

Answer (score 15):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install binutils
greadelf filepath
```

1. install homebrew.
2. use homebrew to install binutils
3. the readelf in binutils is called `greadelf`.

Comment: greadelf requires a flag

Comment: Use `greadelf -a <binary>`, the `-a` flag stands for all options which dumps everything

Comment: `-bash: greadelf: command not found`, with `binutils` installed.

Comment: @hqzxzwb brew doesn't add binutils automatically to your path because "it shadows the host toolchain". Try running /opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin/greadelf (or wherever your brew installation stores stuff).

Answer (score 7):

You might try [`dwarfdump`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dwarfdump/).

⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

Comment: +1 thanks nice tool to know about for those dealing with dwarf debug info

Comment: +1 for available in the Apple toolchain. It is available at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dwarfdump` after Xcode is installed.

Comment: Though you generally don't need the full path: You can just use `xcrun dwarfdump`. And you may have `/usr/bin/dwarfdump` as a shortcut to that, which means you can just type `dwarfdump` and it will Just Work.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried ObjConv? http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv

This utility can be used for converting object files between COFF/PE, OMF, ELF and Mach-O (used by Mac OS) formats for all 32-bit and 64-bit x86 platforms. Can modify symbol names in object files. Can build, modify and convert function libraries across platforms. Can dump object files and executable files. Also includes a very good disassembler supporting the SSE4, AVX, FMA and XOP instruction sets.

Ps.: The source code is included (GPL).

Comment: Nice to meet you carlfilips, and thank you.

Comment: Nice to meet you too. Also, have a look at this http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html