# Nasm on Mac OS X - how to compile and read the debug

Tags: macos, debugging, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to learn assembly and I'm using Nasm v2.10.07 on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard).
I can compile, but I need to read the Debug file, that is a .o file.
This is what I compile:

```
global _main
section.data
M db 5,4,3,2,1
dim equ $-M
section.text
_main:
    mov edi, M
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 1
int 80h
```

This is how I compile:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs myfile.asm -o myfile.o
```

And this is the result:

```
ELF����������������������@�������4�����(�
�������������������������������������������������������������������–������������������������������������?��������������������������������0��M��������������������������������Ä��ê���������������"����������������2������������������*���   �����������P�����������������4��������������`��T����������������:��������������¿��������������������C���    �����������–��0���������������ø����∏����ª���ÕÄ�%define $�The Netwide Assembler 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11)���.text�.comment�.shstrtab�.symtab�.strtab�.rel.text�.stab�.stabstr�.rel.stab��%d����������������������������Òˇ�������������Òˇ������������������������������������������������������Òˇ�������������,�������������myfile.asm�section.data�M�dim�section.text�_main��%define $_%1 ������%define������������d�����������D����������D���������D��
�������D�   ��������D�
�����%define $_%�myfile.asm��%de����� �����,�����8�����D�����P�����
```

So, what should I do to read in the correct way the debug without those strange symbols?

Comment: What are you compiling for? Mac OS X does not use `ELF`, so there are limited tools for looking at such a file.

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286675/readelf-like-tool-for-mac-os-x) should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To show the contents of the `.stabs` section, use `objdump -g myfile.o` or `objdump -G myfile.o`

To get the full source code with line numbers taken from the debug section, use `objdump -S -l myfile.o`

Comment: myfile.o: is not an object file

Comment: Is that a remark, or an error message from `objdump`? Those commands work for me, but it's possible that your version of `objdump` doesn't recognize ELF files.