# LLDB - setting source code path

Tags: c++, c, macos, debugging, lldb

According to the official guideline of lldb, the ability to view source code during debug session (using the command `source list`) is done by setting new pathname for source files.

i.e. if i compiled my project in /tmp on one computer and deployed it on another computer where the source code reside in /Users/Src/ , i should type `settings set target.source-map /tmp /Users/Src` from running lldb in the deployment machine.

However, what happens if i got the executable from someone else, and don't know the build directory. and maybe the source-code is organized differently from where is was built (but the file contents is the same).

my questions are :

1. Does lldb know how to search for matching source file recursively in the supplied path ?
2. How can I get the original pathname form the mach-o executable ?

here's the formal description of the command :

> Remap source file pathnames for the debug session. If your source files are no longer located in the same location as when the program was built --- maybe the program was built on a different computer --- you need to tell the debugger how to find the sources at their local file path instead of the build system's file path.

Comment: I'm not familiar neither of lldb nor osx, but I suggest you try `readelf -a` and `objdump -p` to get some path info from your executable. But `readelf` seems not available in osx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286675/readelf-like-tool-for-mac-os-x

Comment: thanks for you comment. However, ORX executable binary structure is different than ELF and called MACH-O, but i'll try to find synonym to objdump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know a function name in the code in question, do:

```
(lldb) image lookup -vn <FunctionName> <BinaryImageNameContainingFunction>
```

and look for the `CompileUnit` entry.  The path given there is the path lldb got from the debug information.

Comment: I desperately try to use that on Mac OSX to lookup the default path for a C++ function from a Qt framework.... image lookup -vn QStyledItemDelegate::paint /Users/leo/Qt_online/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui gives "warning: Unable to find an image that matches '/Users/leo/Qt_online/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/QtGui' (so the question is probably how to specify frameworks)

Comment: You can just supply the base name (QtGui in your case) which is simpler and all you need unless you have a bundle & shared library with the same base name.  Not sure why the full path didn't work for you.  The `image list` command will list all the images, see if you can find the library there.  Maybe there's a symlink in the path somewhere so you and lldb are spelling it differently?

Comment: `image list` is the super command I was looking for...turned out my QtGui is spelled `/Users/leo/Qt_online/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui` (and that there is no `QStyledItemDelegate::paint`  in it, but `image lookup -vn paint /Users/leo/Qt_online/5.15.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui` gives me all `paint` functions in that framework), thanks a lot!