# How to use atos? (or addr2line on Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, binutils, addr2line

I see the following example using `addr2line`. But the interfaces of `atos` and `addr2line` are different. I am not sure how to make it work using `atos`. Could anybody show me how to convert it to using `atos`?

https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/

Alternatively, is there a way to make addr2line work on Mac (It is known that addr2line does not work well on Mac OS X)? I just get `??` instead of function names using `addr2line`. Thanks.

Comment: The “`??`” symbol indicates that addr2line has no debug information on that address ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [readelf-like tool for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286675/readelf-like-tool-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: Why it is duplicated? The link you referred mentioned nothing about atos.

Comment: It’s “possible duplicate”; there’s an answer there that mentioned installing MacPorts binutils, maybe have a look at that and if it doesn’t solve your problem report back and I’ll reverse the close vote.

Comment: It is known that addr2line does not work well on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways `addr2line` is used in the script in the article you linked:

```
addr2line -f -e ${EXECUTABLE} ${FADDR}
```

and:

```
addr2line -s -e ${EXECUTABLE} ${CADDR}
```

The first one uses the `-f` option, which causes `addr2line` to output the function name on a line by itself before showing the filename and line number on a second line. In that script, only the first line is used (it's piped through `head -1`).

`atos` always outputs the function name, so there's no need for an equivalent to that `-f` option. [Whereas `addr2line` is short for "address to line" (filename and line number), making the function name ancillary to its main purpose, `atos` is short for "address to symbol", so producing the symbol name is its core purpose.]

The next option used for `addr2line` is `-e ${EXECUTABLE}`. The equivalent for `atos` is `-o ${EXECUTABLE}`.

After that, the arguments are addresses. That's the same between `addr2line` and `atos`.

So, the `atos` command that corresponds to `addr2line -f -e ${EXECUTABLE} ${FADDR}`
 is `atos -o ${EXECUTABLE} ${FADDR}`. **However**, the script is "parsing" the output from the command and the two programs produce output in different formats. To get just the function name from the output of `atos`, you can pipe it through `perl -lne 'print "$1" if m/^(.*) \(in .*\)/'`.

The second type of `addr2line` command does not use the `-f` option, so it doesn't print the function name. It's just used to get the filename and line number. As mentioned before, `atos` always prints the function name. So, the `atos` command is the same as before. To get just the file name and line number from its output, you can pipe it through `perl -lne 'print "$1" if m/^.* \(in .*\) \((.*)\)$/'`.

This `addr2line` command also uses the `-s` option. That makes it print only the basename of the file path, not the whole path. That's what `atos` does anyway, so there's no need to translate that option to anything.

Comment: I tried it. But it just print the original address `$ atos -o main.exe 0x7fff569f0015\n
0x7fff569f0015`. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: My guess is that your program was loaded at a (somewhat) randomized address due to ASLR. If that happens, you have to pass either the load address or the slide to `atos` or it won't be able to match addresses to symbols. You can prevent it by linking the program with the `-no_pie` linker option. (If the compiler is driving the linker, as it often is, you would pass it as `-Wl,-no_pie`.)

Comment: OK. This works most of the time. But it occasionally says `atos[79546]: [fatal]  child process status could not be determined; exit code unavailable.` Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. Are you using `-o <image file path>` or `-p <pid>`? The mention of a child process makes me think the latter, but maybe it runs some internal helper process and that's what it's talking about.

Comment: I used the command that you mentioned with -o. Since the process is finished, there is no way to specify the pid.

Comment: Are you maybe running a gazillion instances of `atos` simultaneously?