# significance of different hex address with call stack trace

Tags: ios, memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, stack-trace

what is the significance of all these different hexadecimal address (**in bold**) ? how to get exact problematic line number of source code for dumped function below from this hex address of crash dump stack for ios platform build specifically. I know add2line is used to get line number from hex address for linux platform.

```
==8587==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x611000112680 at pc 0x000124c4c2e5 bp 0x700003c58130 sp 0x700003c58128
READ of size 8 at 0x611000112680 thread T32
```

#0 **0x124c4c2e4** in fun1(param1,param2, param3)+**0xac4** (TestApp:x86_64+**0x122eba2e4**)

#1 0x124c4d88a in fun2(param1)+0x29a (TestApp:x86_64+0x122ebb88a)

Answer (score 0):

> what is the significance of all these different hexadecimal address

The first number (`0x124c4c2e4`) is the instruction address where the `heap-use-after-free` is detected.

The second number: `0xac4` says that address `0x124c4c2e4` is the same as `& fun1()+0xac4`, that is the bad access is happening inside `fun1()`.

The last number tells you which binary the problem function is located in, and at what offset from where this binary is mapped.

IOW, we can deduce that `&fun1() == 0x124c4c2e4 - 0xac4 == 0x124c4b820` and that the `TestApp` is mapped at `0x124c4c2e4 - 0x122eba2e4 == 0x1d92000`.

> how to get exact problematic line number of source code

You must compile your code with debug info. Note: addresses may change -- you need to re-build with `-g` and get a new report.

> I know add2line is used to get line number from hex address for linux platform.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320860/50617) might help.